# Couldn't Train Tensor Object Detection API Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow's object detection API. I successfully trained with 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17' model, later I moved to another model from the given models but while training process starts it showing the error:
    "TypeError: Expected int32, got range <0,3> of type 'range' instead".
This error was thrown for all other models other than the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.

I used 300*300 size images for training for all the models.
Here I attached images of the command prompt window showing the error message.I use tensorflow version is 1.5 and python 3.6.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify
line 154 : tf.constant(range(num_boundaries), dtype=tf.int32),
to tf.constant(list(range(num_boundaries)), dtype=tf.int32)

For further reference :
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3443